# Linq two tables in to one

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I got two tables:

1. Id, FirtsName, LastName, Adress, Date
2. Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Tel, Date

now I would like to receive result:

- Id, FirtsName, LastName, Adress, Date
- Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Tel, Date
- Id, FirtsName, LastName, Adress, Date
- Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Tel, Date
- Id, FirtsName, LastName, Adress, Date
- Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Tel, Date

How to do that by using Linq?

Ok I'm own farther explanation, this is my task: There must be a relation between the two in order to collect information from both tables at the same time to create pre-populated PDF. I must use Linq and MVC 4.5

I thought it's gonna be easy but after christmas I've got some mind blinds.

this is what I would like to achieve:

```
var last24h = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);
        var resultL = db.Loans.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= last24h).Select( p=> new PDFList() {
            Id = p.Id,
            Amount = p.Amount,
            Term = p.Term,
            Purpose = p.Purpose,
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            Address = p.Address,
            Email = p.Email,
            PropertyValue = 0,
            CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate,
            Seen = p.Seen,
            AdvisorId = p.AdvisorId
        });
        var resultM = db.Mortgages.Where(p => p.CreatedDate >= last24h).Select(p => new PDFList()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Amount = p.Amount,
            Term = p.Term,
            Purpose = "",
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            Address = p.Address,
            Email = p.Email,
            PropertyValue = p.PropertyValue,
            CreatedDate = p.CreatedDate,
            Seen = p.Seen,
            AdvisorId = p.AdvisorId
        });
        var resultLM = resultL.Concat(resultM).OrderByDescending(p=>p.CreatedDate).ToList();
```

Comment: what are your table names?

Comment: Looks like you want to oscillate between tables?  That is very strange. IE 1,2,1,2... is that correct? Definitely need a _lot_ more detail if you expect us to be able to help.  Are the IDs the same? Are they sequential? Etc...

Comment: Me thinks you are trying to put a screw into the wood using a hammer... you may be able to get the job done but there is probably a better tool for the job.

Comment: Result in what context?  Collection of objects?  HTML Table? CSV file?  Your "result" does not have consistent fields

Comment: This sucks as concept. This is a union of alternating rows, so totally not what SQL is about. You should join and then do the split in whatever front end you use to generate the report. This is "back top SQL for beginners and 'what is a select statement'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below mentioned type inner join for your tables.Try it.

**This is a Sample for Linq inner join**

```
public void Linq102() 
{ 

    string[] categories = new string[]{  
        "Beverages",   
        "Condiments",   
        "Vegetables",   
        "Dairy Products",   
        "Seafood" };  

    List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 

    var q = 
        from c in categories 
        join p in products on c equals p.Category 
        select new { Category = c, p.ProductName }; 

    foreach (var v in q) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(v.ProductName + ": " + v.Category);  
    } 
}
```

You can get more details [**LINQ - Join Operators Here**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9)

I hope this will help to you.